# How to show TableLayout and hidden other TableLayout in 1 onClick

Tags: android

I'm trying to build an application with showing `TableLayout1` and hidding `TableLayout2` in same time when `img1` pressed, but im still got error...

This is my java code :

```
public class Info extends ActionBarActivity {
ImageView img1;
TableLayout tl, tl2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_info);
        tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.infolayout);
        tl2 = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.trueident);
        img1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        
        
        img1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                tl.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                tl2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  

            }
        });
        
    }

    
}
```

So the point is, i want show `trueident` layout who are hidden, and hide `infolayout` who already visible since beginning.

Are this is possible? also, how should i write the code for `if` to do the opposite when `img1` already pressed?!

Answer (score 0):

All works fine for me. Check your files and compare with this. Also provide here what "says" your android monitor.

My code:

```
package com.example.android.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;

 public class Info extends ActionBarActivity {
   ImageView img1;
   TableLayout tl, tl2;

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.infolayout);
    tl2 = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.trueident);
    img1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    img1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            tl.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            tl2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    });

}


}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.android.myapplication.Info"
android:id="@+id/activity_info"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="264dp"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="130dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="135dp" />

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/infolayout"
    android:layout_width="193dp"
    android:layout_height="107dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">
</TableLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/trueident"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="103dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    >
</TableLayout>

 </TableLayout>
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.myapplication">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Info">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```